# Fit a Gaussian to measured peak

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting, gaussian

I have a small spectrum peak and I'm trying to fit a Gaussian function to it. I searched an example online and mixed the code with the one I made.

```
wveleng=[ 639.188  639.454  639.719  639.985  640.25   640.516  640.781  641.046
      641.312  641.577]
    counts=[   778.    1613.8  12977.4  32990.   33165.2  13171.    2067.2    900.8
        788.8    747.8]
```

my first code is the following

```
def gaus(x,a,mu,sigma):
    return a*exp(-(x-mu)**2/(2*sigma**2))

    a=ydata.max()
x0=ydata.mean()
sigm=ydata.std()

mean = sum(ydata*xdata)/len(ydata)
sigma = np.sqrt(sum(ydata*(xdata-mean)**2)/len(ydata))

#print(ydata.max())
popt, pcov = curve_fit(Gauss, xdata,ydata,maxfev=991,p0=[a,x0,sigm])    
#gmodel = Model(Gauss)
#result = gmodel.fit(ydata, x=xdata, a=ydata.max(),x0=ydata.mean(),sigm=ydata.std())
print(popt)
#plt.scatter(xdata,ydata,label='data points')
#plt.plot(xdata, result.best_fit, 'r-')
#popt, pcov = curve_fit(gauss, xdata, ydata,p0=[ydata.max(), ydata.mean(), ydata.std()])
xx = np.linspace(639,642, 10)
plt.plot(xx, gauss(xdata, *popt), 'r-', label='fit')
```

with plot i get the following.

[image]

i think it has to do with initial guess parameters

a second code which i find more compact and suits better for me.

```
    def gauss(x, a, x0, sigma):
    return a * np.exp(-(x - x0) ** 2 / (2 * sigma ** 2))

ydata = np.array([778.,1613.8,12977.4,32990.,33165.2,13171.,2067.2,900.8,788.8,747.8])

xx = np.arange(639,642, 100)
xdata=np.array([639.188,639.454,639.719,639.985,640.250,640.516,640.781,641.046,641.312,641.577])


#plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'bo', label='data')
def Gauss(x, a, x0, sigm):
    return a * np.exp(-(x - x0)**2 / (2 * sigm**2))

gmodel = Model(Gauss)
result = gmodel.fit(ydata, x=xdata, a=ydata.max(),x0=ydata.mean(),sigm=ydata.std())
plt.scatter(xdata,ydata,label='data points')
plt.plot(xdata, result.best_fit, 'r-')
```

i get exactly the same fit as the 1st method. Is there a way fit more points in than the data itself

Comment: You need to include the FULL error message so we can see which function raises the error. This error means that one of the function was expecting an argument that is an `iterable` (as a list or a numpy array) and that it received a single `float` number instead.

Comment: I don't know what you might be doing wrong. This does seem a long-winded way of going about it. You might wish to look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/42029398/131187.

Comment: @BillBell thnx for the advice i looked at the other question .. that will help a loot

Comment: @Eskapp i added the error messages i still dont yet understand what i did wrong

Comment: You might try this example of fitting carbon nanotube Raman spectroscopy data to a double Lorentzian peak equation, it uses scipy's scipy.optimize.differential_equation genetic algorithm to find initial parameter values - that scipy module uses the Latin Hypercube algorithm to ensure a thorough search of parameter space. The URL on bitbucket is https://bitbucket.org/zunzuncode/ramanspectroscopyfit/ If you change the equation and data to your own, it should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are really close, though I have to admit I do not understand what `xx` is meant to represent.  You definitely want the data to be fit (`ydata`) and the independent variable (`xdata`) to be the same length.

I think the main problem you are running into now is that your initial guesses are not very good, and that you will get good results with

```
result = gmodel.fit(ydata, x=xdata, a=ydata.max(), x0=xdata.mean(), sigma=xdata.std())
```

(with `xdata` instead of `ydata` controlling the initial values for `x0` and `sigma`).

Perhaps even better would be to add some sanity checks to the range of parameter values, as with

```
params = gmodel.make_params(a=ydata.max(),
                            x0=xdata.mean(),
                            sigma=xdata.std())
params['x0'].min = min(xdata)
params['x0'].max = max(xdata)
params['sigma'].max = 5
result = gmodel.fit(ydata, params, x=xdata)
```

Finally, using the built-in models like GaussianModel will report both `sigma` and `fwhm` and also `amplitude` (that is, integral of the Gaussian) and `height` (the maximum value the Gaussian would take).  So, this script:

```
import numpy as np
from lmfit.models import GaussianModel
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ydata = np.array([778.,1613.8,12977.4,32990.,33165.2,13171.,2067.2,900.8,788.8,747.8])
xdata = np.array([639.188,639.454,639.719,639.985,640.250,640.516,640.781,641.046,641.312,641.577])

gmodel = GaussianModel()
params = gmodel.make_params(amplitude=ydata.max(),
                            center=xdata.mean(),
                            sigma=xdata.std())
result = gmodel.fit(ydata, params, x=xdata)

print(result.fit_report())
plt.scatter(xdata,ydata,label='data points')
plt.plot(xdata, result.best_fit, 'r-')
plt.show()
```

will print out

```
[[Model]]
    Model(gaussian)
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # function evals   = 27
    # data points      = 10
    # variables        = 3
    chi-square         = 2360971.771
    reduced chi-square = 337281.682
    Akaike info crit   = 129.720
    Bayesian info crit = 130.628
[[Variables]]
    sigma:       0.27525232 +/- 0.004505 (1.64%) (init= 0.7623906)
    center:      640.119396 +/- 0.004490 (0.00%) (init= 640.3828)
    amplitude:   25633.2702 +/- 362.5571 (1.41%) (init= 33165.2)
    fwhm:        0.64816968 +/- 0.010608 (1.64%)  == '2.3548200*sigma'
    height:      37152.0777 +/- 525.0717 (1.41%)  == '0.3989423*amplitude/max(1.e-15, sigma)'
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are <  0.100)
    C(sigma, amplitude)          =  0.579
```

and give a pretty good-looking fit.   For advanced practice, I recommend trying to add a ConstantModel() to give a background offset.   Well, and collect more data points ;).

Comment: i added   offset model with this code.. but i get 9900 as c-value which is not correct i think                                       
back=ConstantModel()
par=back.make_params(c=ydata.min())
background=back.fit(ydata, par, x=xdata)
print(background.fit_report())

Answer (score 1):

scipy.integrate.quad is not doing convolution, as you seem to expect.  `quad(function, lower_bound, upper_bound)[0]` will return a single value for the integral of the function between the bounds.

OTOH, `curve_fit(func, ...)` needs an array of values for the model function, and it is complaining that it got a float, not an ndarray.

Maybe you intended to do `curve_fit(vfunc, ...)`?

You might find lmfit (https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/) useful.  It has convenient, high-level tools curve-fitting, and simple model functions like Gaussian are built in. It also has a mechanism for fitting a model that is the sum or product of two function, and can even create a model that consists of the convolution of two functions.   For example of this, see the examples described in https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/model.html#composite-models-adding-or-multiplying-models.

Comment: @M Newville thank you for your reply. at the moment  i m trying to solve this problem with the second method. i still get a straight line despite effort of changing the guessed parameters

Comment: @M Newville i have tried to solve my problem with the method u proposed. however i have not yet good results as i problaby need more points. i tried generating points with as apply this by replacing x=xdata with x=xx however i get error saying x and y are of not same dimension,  see above figure, thank you.